# Efficient way to build a map of tree relationship from List<Object[]>

Tags: java, oracle, algorithm, performance, tree

When I query my database it returns me `List<Object[]>` where `object[]` contains Parent, Child, and GrandChild. I want to build a map of this tree relationship as `Map<Parent, Map<Child, List<GrandChild>>>`. I want to know the fastest way of building this relationship.

I can either do it by breaking my DB query into multiple queries like first building `Map<Parent, List<Child>>` then use each of `List<Child>` to retrieve grandchild list, However this option will exponentially increase the number of times I need to query the DB if the count of elements is high Or use the below code to convert List to Map.

```
private Map<Long, Map<String, List<String>>> objectListToMap(List<Object[]> list) {
        Map<Long, Map<String, List<String>>> hmap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Object[] object : list) {
            Map<String, List<String>> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
            if (!hmap.containsKey(Long.parseLong(object[0].toString()))) {
                hmap.put(Long.parseLong(object[0].toString()), innerMap);
            }
            for (Object[] object1 : list) {
                if (Long.valueOf(object[0].toString()).equals(Long.valueOf(object1[0].toString()))) {
                    if (!innerMap.containsKey(object1[1].toString())) {
                        innerMap.put(object1[1].toString(), new ArrayList<String>());
                    }
                    innerMap.get(object1[1].toString()).add(object1[2].toString());
                }
            }
            hmap.get(Long.valueOf(object[0].toString())).putAll(innerMap);
        }
        return hmap;
    }
```

Please let me know how can I reduce the processing time.

Comment: First not sure why you would want to build such complex map. You might be better designing some classes to store your data. For example build a class such as `class MyObject {  List<MyObject> children; }` You could easily go to your grand children starting from parent just like you traverse a tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, there are two for loops running one another i.e. n*n loops. we can remove one for loop inside another for loop and run the second for loop outside with objects that will contain only  `List<object>[]` for each key of the outer map.

```
private Map<Long, Map<String, List<String>>> objectListToMap(List<Object[]> list) {

        List<Object[]> objList = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Long, Map<String, List<String>>> hmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<Long, List<Object[]>> tempmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (Object[] object : list) {
            if (!hmap.containsKey(Long.parseLong(object[0].toString()))) {
                hmap.put(Long.parseLong(object[0].toString()), new HashMap<String, List<String>>());
                tempmap.put(Long.parseLong(object[0].toString()), objList);
            }
            tempmap.get(Long.parseLong(object[0].toString())).add(object);
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Long, List<Object[]>> entry : tempmap.entrySet()) {
            Map<String, List<String>> innerMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            for (Object[] obj : entry.getValue()) {
                if (!innerMap.containsKey(obj[1].toString())) {
                    innerMap.put(obj[1].toString(), new ArrayList<String>());
                }
                innerMap.get(obj[1].toString()).add(obj[2].toString());
            }
            hmap.get(entry.getKey()).putAll(innerMap);
        }

        return hmap;
    }
```